# Audio pack into exe

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to include an audio file, like the images can be done, into the output exe file in .NET ? c#

I've been looking around and wow, this apparently isn't used that much?

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: I'm using System.Media.SoundPlayer to select a file from the system and I have no idea how to include it in the exe , thanks for reading soner

Answer (score 2):

Add your file to the resources of the assembly.

1. Open properties of your project.
2. Go to the "Resources" tab. Click Add Resource -> Add Existing File.
3. Change the name of this resource if you want.

Now you can play it like this (provided that I named the resource as MyWavResource):

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.MyWavResouce);
player.Play();
```

Comment: I'd like to note that this works with all sorts of files, as anything that's not one of the standard resource types is simply compiled into the resources as `byte[]`. That way you can store anything in the resources, from audio to ZIP files.